# Ownership contact info

Tags: ownership

I went to the recommended gov site to do a search but could not find the patent.  It is listed on google search.  How do I find the owners contact info?

Comment: Hey Ed, welcome to Ask Patents. Would it be possible to toss over the patent or application number? A link to the Google Patents page would be great.

Comment: US Public Pair is really picky about the format for patent numbers. You also need to pick the right type of number (application, patent, document, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

For United States Patent applications or patents and some PCT applications filed in the US, you can look at the USPTO system called assignments on the web.

http://www.uspto.gov/patent/laws-and-regulations/power-attorney-and-assignment/assignments-web-aotw

Generally, you are only going to get a full set of information for US applications that have been published or have matured into an issued patent.  Unpublished applications, including those with non-publication requests won't share all the details unless and until the application is subsequently published, the patent issues, or an application is used as a priority document for a later application that is published or issued.

You can also go in through Public PAIR at USPTO for the relevant application or patent and hit the assignments tab.

Some applications are owned by the original inventors and no assignment is filed.  Some have been assigned but the owners have not gone through the prudent step of recording the assignment. It is also possible that there have been subsequent assignments after an initial assignment that have not yet been recorded.  There can be a time lag between an attempt by an owner to record an assignment and the assignment showing up in the records, but generally the lag is only a week or so.

So checking the public records is a good step but not all assignments are properly recorded.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

It's an extremely easy process. Regarding US patents:

1. You can use any patent search engine such as https://patents.google.com to search the patent. I think you mentioned that you already found the patent there.
2. Then, the current owner (*Current Assignee*) should be listed on the right side. You can perform a web search on that name (usually a company) and reach them out.
3. And if you want to reach out the inventor, just perform the same process with them!

Comment: The US Public Pair does provide a correspondence address (often the patent lawyers) which can be helpful especially if the assignee is the inventor.